# Switch beetween CPU and GPU rendering in Silverlight XNA project

Tags: silverlight, 3d, xna, gpu

I have a project in Silverlight that uses XNA for 3D graphics. I would like to make it run properly on computers with old graphics cards that do not support SM 2.0. I found one tutorial, but I couldn't follow included steps because Silverlight version of Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll does not include some required methods.

How to switch to CPU rendering in Silverlight XNA projects?
//btw, tutorial that I talked about: http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/ShortTuts/Reference_device.php
I got an error:

> 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsAdapter' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultAdapter'

Comment: You should try to ask this question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/